# Playing you tube video in Webview in iOS 9.0.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, youtube, ios9

I am getting an issue while playing a `youtube` video using `webView`. I am giving one `html` string as an input in which `youtube` video `url` is provided. My `webView` is loading successfully. Also in  delegate of `webViewDidFinishLoad`, I can get the proper url using - `webView.request.URL.absoluteString`

But strange fact is, I cant see any interface except `webview`'s background color. This is happening on `iOS 9.0.2.` On `simulator` of `iOS 9.0.` its working fine.

Also, on the device with `iOS 8.3` it's working fine. Only on the device of `iOS 9.0.2` it's not working.

Below is the code I wrote so far -

```
NSString *strLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/%@/clean",strVidID];

            youTubeVideoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                             <html>\
                             <head>\
                             <style type=\"text/css\">\
                             iframe {position:absolute; margin-top:-0px;}\
                             body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
                             </style>\
                             </head>\
                             <body>\
                             <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"100%%\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
                             </body>\
                             </html>", strLink];

            [self.webVwVideoPlayer loadHTMLString:youTubeVideoHTML baseURL:baseURL];
```

where, `self.webVwVideoPlayer` is outlet to `UIWebView`.

Also, as per new **app transport security**, I have modified my `plist` file as -

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
    <key>youtube.com</key>
    <dict>
    <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
    <true/>


    <!--Include to allow insecure HTTP requests-->
    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>


    <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
    <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
    </dict>
    </dict>
```

Please let me know if anyone know about this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit). It seamlessly adds youtube video to your app without the need of UIWebView.

It uses progressive download + MoviePlayer and AVFoundation frameworks. Just supply it with a youtube video ID and you are good to go.

It supports both full-screen & non full-screen and WORKS ON iOS SIMULATOR!!!

Example:

```
XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:@"9bZkp7q19f0"];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
```

Comment: are you sure? I got this message there - "XCDYouTubeKit is against the YouTube Terms of Service. The only official way of playing a YouTube video inside an app is with a web view and the iframe player API. Unfortunately, this is very slow and quite ugly, so I wrote this player to give users a better viewing experience".

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIWebView *video=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, SCREEN_WIDTH-20, 180)];
            video.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
            NSString *strHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" width=\"280\" height=\"185\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>",@"8syP39rL2kY"];
            NSString *htmlStringToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/%@",@"8syP39rL2kY"];
            [video loadHTMLString:strHtml baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:htmlStringToLoad]];
            [self.view addSubview:video];
```

Comment: what you want me to do here? u want me to create and allocate uiwebview programmatically? This is also not helping

Comment: dude, I really cant see anything new in your code. I am just pissed off why the hell webview is loading successfully with provided HTML and not showing anything!!!! while its working smoothly till iOS 8.4 on actual devices and with iOS 9.0 simulator!! but not on the actual device with iOS 9.0.2!!!

Comment: ok u can happy with your code but right now my code is working in all devices accepted iOS 9.0.2..

Comment: hahah lol. It would be great if I come to know technical reason rather than some bunch of code. Anyway thanks!